# What is the difference between making app using mongodart package and rest api in flutter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, flutter

Hi I have recently started to make andriod app.At first i made it using firestore but as i started learning a bit more i realized as per as my requirement firestore would be costly so i shift to mongodb. The i came to know about mongodart package so i started building it using mongidart soon i realized that there are certain features missing in mingodart like the db.watch to monitor realime changes and also the data fetching time from mongodb is bit slow(I might be wrong as i am a new learner).
Now my question is will i be able to solve the problem like slow fetching the data from database also monitor realtime changes if i build it using rest api(NODE jS + Flutter + Mongodb).
Please help me out i need to deploy an app very soon.
Is there any difference between building a flutter app using mongodart package and restapi